# How to dynamically name UIButtons within a loop  and how to do animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, uibutton

I create in this code 7 buttons with different names, and set the tag and frame for each button.

If I click a particular button it calls `buttonPresed:` and goes into the switch statement, branching according to the tag.
However, if I click one of button 1,2,3,4,5, or 6, then the last button moves up and down. I don't want that button to move; I want each button, according to tag, to move.

```
-(void)btnMethod
{
    for(int i1=0;i1<[characters11arrary count];i1++)
    {
        NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]init];
                  str=[characters11arrary objectAtIndex:i1];

        NSInteger idcard = [str integerValue];
        idcard--;

        btn=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-15,140+w11,70,55)];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[arrayPlayerCard objectAtIndex:idcard] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        btn.tag=j11;
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPresed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn];     
        w11+=20;
        j11+=1; 
        idcard=0;
    }

}
-(void)buttonPresed:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btnTag=(UIButton*)sender;
    d =btnTag.tag;
    NSLog(@"tagc= %i",d);
  switch(d)
    {
        case 1:
            if(t==1)
            {

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];           
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
            [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
            CGAffineTransform transform1 =CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(30,0);               

            [btn setTransform:transform1];              
             t=0;
             break;
            }
            else //if(t==0)
            {
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];           
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
                [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
                CGAffineTransform transform1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);   
                [btn setTransform:transform1];
                t=1;
                break;

            }
case 2:....................................
.......................................................
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you use `[btn setTransform:...]`instead of `[sender setTransform:...]`
think 'btn' has the address of the last allocated Button, so your function moves everytime the last button.

and if you use sender you dont need the switch.

```
-(void)buttonPresed:(id)sender
{
if ([sender transform].ty == 0) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];           
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:  1];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    CGAffineTransform transform1 =CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-30);               

    [sender setTransform:transform1];  
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
else{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];           
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:  1];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    CGAffineTransform transform1 =CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);               

    [sender setTransform:transform1];  
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}
```

this works, but your translation does a right-left animation not up-down, changed that in my code